# Simple query - why is it throwing errors?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a really difficult time getting this query to process without errors. Can you get me on the right track? I've been fiddling with variations for about an hour.

As you can see, I am trying to get a total record count of `casetype_txt` fields that equal `'DONATION'`, and then on the `B` table get all the `Groups` that are not empty values. So, one total count number is what I am trying to achieve.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(casetype_txt)

FROM
  amd_full_merged_st_load_case AS a

WHERE
  a.casetype_txt = 'DONATION'

LEFT JOIN amd_full_merged_st_load_case AS b
  ON a.case_id=b.case_id

WHERE b.group != '';
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is not correct, give this a try,

```
SELECT  COUNT(casetype_txt) 
FROM    amd_full_merged_st_load_case AS a 
        LEFT JOIN amd_full_merged_st_load_case AS b
            ON  a.case_id = b.case_id AND
                b.group != ''
WHERE   a.casetype_txt = 'DONATION'
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 1):

Lets this, one at a time.

First, the table `JOIN`s are to be made in the `FROM` clause. `WHERE` clause comes after that. So, a valid query would be (notice that we can't have 2 `WHERE` clause in a simple query so the two conditions have to be combined with an `AND` - or sometimes with an `OR` but probably not the case here):

```
-- Version 1 --
SELECT
  COUNT(a.casetype_txt)

FROM
  amd_full_merged_st_load_case AS a

  LEFT JOIN amd_full_merged_st_load_case AS b
    ON a.case_id=b.case_id

WHERE
  a.casetype_txt = 'DONATION'

  AND b.group <> '' ;
```

Now, because you have a condition about the `b` table (the one on the right side of a `LEFT` outer join) in the `WHERE` clause, this makes the outer join work as an inner join. SO, the above query is equivalent to:

```
-- Version 2 --
SELECT
  COUNT(a.casetype_txt)

FROM
  amd_full_merged_st_load_case AS a

  INNER JOIN amd_full_merged_st_load_case AS b
    ON a.case_id=b.case_id

WHERE
  a.casetype_txt = 'DONATION'

  AND b.group <> '' ;
```

The above (version 2) is likely what you are after. There is another catch though. Depending on the relationship between the two tables (1-1, 1-n, n-1, n-n), the query may give a wrong count, since the join may produce many rows for a specific `case_id`. So, you should also check if converting the joins to semi-joins (using `EXISTS` subquery) gives you the answer you seek:

```
-- Version 3a --
SELECT
  COUNT(a.*)                                     -- we want to count rows

FROM
  amd_full_merged_st_load_case AS a              -- from table a

WHERE                                            -- where
  a.casetype_txt = 'DONATION'                    -- casetype is DONATION
                                                 -- and
  AND EXISTS                                     -- at least one 
      ( SELECT *                                 -- (related row) exists
        FROM amd_full_merged_st_load_case AS b   -- in table b
        WHERE a.case_id = b.case_id              
          AND b.group <> ''
      ) ;
```

or:

```
-- Version 3b --
SELECT
  COUNT(b.*)                                     -- we want to count rows

FROM
  amd_full_merged_st_load_case AS b              -- from table b

WHERE                                            -- where
  b.group <> ''                                  -- group is not empty
                                                 -- and
  AND EXISTS                                     -- at least one 
      ( SELECT *                                 -- (related row) exists
        FROM amd_full_merged_st_load_case AS a   -- in table a
        WHERE a.case_id = b.case_id              
          AND a.casetype_txt = 'DONATION'        
      ) ;
```